# Why activity_main.xml not created automatically when Empty Activity option selected?

Tags: kotlin, file, android-activity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7p1S.png)

I am running latest Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2

I installed it on both laptops to see if I got the same issue, which I did.

Each time I create an Empty Activity the res/layout folder is not created. Also the activity_main.xml file is not created as well. From all the tutorials I have seen on youtube I should have the activity_main.xml file created as well.
Am I missing a setting or is there something wrong or changed in Android Studio?

I tried installing it on other machines to see if it was hardware.
I did a basic activity project option and the folders and file was created.

Answer (score 2):

On Android Studio Flamingo if you choose **Empty Activity**, you will create Android project with [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose). Please choose **Empty Views Activity** to create Android project with XML.